# ejsで普通に出力したい時

Tags: javascript, node.js

`ejs`で`<%= %>`を使わずに文字を表示させるにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

例えば以下のような時、書き方がわかりません。

```
<a href="" class="<%
// 条件によってclassにactiveを追加
if (hoge) {
  "active"
}
%>">
```

Answer (score 1):

手元に環境がないので恐縮ですが、下記でいかがでしょうか？

```
<% var active = hoge ? "active" : "" %>
<a href="" class="<%= active %>">>
```